# Customer Groups and product_price_index in Magento

Tags: magento, indexing

Magento seems to create a product_price_index row for each product X customer_group_id even if a given customer_group_id doesn't have a price for the product.

This ends up in a problem such: I have 4675 products and 285 customers. A given customer might only have 1 special price for 1 product, and no more, but still I get 4675x285 = 1332375 rows in the index, which thus becomes un-manageable, making each reindex a real pain.

Does any magento guru out there have any ideas about how to handle this situation?

Comment: Try to enable / disable flat data, one milion rows in index is not a standard behavior of Magento.